# Int to hex conversion

Tags: ruby, hex, string-formatting

Concerning the following line(from [here](https://community.rapid7.com/community/metasploit/blog/2006/04/06/post-exploitation-fun-in-metasploit-30)):

```
"%.8x" % 7929856 #=> "00790000"
```

I don't understand what is done with `7929856` to get the value `"00790000"`. I know that `0x790000` is `7929856` in hexadecimal, but I don't know where the two leading zeros came from. Is this simply a method of converting the number to hexadecimal? Can someone explain what is happening there?

Comment: You could look at http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Kernel.html#method-i-sprintf (which the syntax `"foo" % x` is invoking) although it covers a wide range of examples without demonstrating anything like `"%.8x"` clearly.

Comment: "I know that `0x790000` is `7929856` in hexadecimal" -- Do you mean the other way around?

Comment: As in it IS that number, but in hex form

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `"%.8x"` is `%x` with a minimum precision specified.  In this case, 8 digits.  So if you gave it:

```
"%.8x" % 1
> '00000001'
```

The result will always have at least 8 digits, maybe more.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not terribly familiar with Ruby, but my guess (from similar syntax in C) is that the "8" in "%.8x" means to display 8 digits.